# Cloudformation update stack policy condition on stack name or environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, serverless, policy

I have a policy attached to my CloudFormation stack:

```json
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "Update:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Action": [
        "Update:Replace",
        "Update:Delete"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ResourceType": [
            "AWS::SNS::Topic",
            "AWS::SQS::Queue"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The policy prevents accidental deleting of SNS/SQS resources. I want to make the policy more liberal in a `dev` environment. How do I disable the `Deny` statement conditionally, for example, if my CF (cloudformation) stack name is `my-app-dev` or the CF stack has a tag `STAGE` equal to `dev`?

Btw the policy is generated by the serverless framework, so I will have to write it in serverless.yml

Comment: How exactly do you generate such a policy in your template? How do you specify dev environment?

Comment: It's automatically generated from serverless.yml.

Comment: I have a tag `STAGE` on the stack - it says for example `dev test prod`.
I am also using different stack names for different envs.
For example  `my-app-dev`  `my-app-test`  `my-app-prod`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using the environment variables of the serverless framework.

serverless.yml

```yaml
service: sample

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${opt:stage,"dev"}
  region: ap-northeast-1

custom:
  policyChange: 
    prd: Deny
    dev: Allow

resources:
  - ${file(iam.yml)}
```

iam.yml

```yaml
Resources:
  SampleRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: SampleRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: SamplePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
            - Effect: '${self:custom.policyChange.${self:provider.stage}}'
              Resource: "*"
              Action:
              - sqs:*
```

Comment: It is also possible to embed the policy directly in `serverless.yml`